# CDF of a r.v. with a negative power in its PDF

Tags: probability, density-function

I need to compute a CDF knowing the PDF of a random variable, so nothing fancy.

[image]

I find the constant c by stating that:

[image]

I find $c = 0.5114$

But when I want to determine the CDF and its bounds, I have a problem

[image]

My CDF becomes negative, and for a non-negative function, it is quiet a problem
Do you see the problem and could you give me a hint ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CDF is an antiderivative of the PDF but generally not the "trivial" one given to us by the elementary calculus rules. To illustrate this, instead of doing your problem, I will do a related problem, namely finding the CDF of a random variable with PDF $f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x<0 \\ e^{-x} & x \geq 0 \end{cases}$. Then the CDF is

$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(y) dy=\begin{cases} 0 & x<0 \\ \int_0^x e^{-y} dy & x \geq 0 \end{cases}.$$

We compute this integral:

$$\int_0^x e^{-y} dy = -e^{-x}-(-1)=1-e^{-x}.$$

Note the term from the endpoint $0$, which is necessary in order to keep $F$ from being negative, since the "trivial" antiderivative is indeed negative.

Essentially the same thing happens in your problem: there will be a term from the endpoint $1$ which keeps $F$ from being negative.

Comment: So if I get you right, I should change the bounds of my integral, but thus, will I not change the information which is given in the PDF ? How would my CDF look like if I follow your idea ?

Comment: @endlessend2525 The point is that to get the CDF for $x$ between $1$ and $1991$ you need to integrate the PDF from $1$ to $x$, and the endpoint $1$ will give you a positive constant term like in my example.

Comment: I must have been too much tired. Thanks a lot !